# Reducing filesize for TIFF rasters

Tags: qgis, raster, r, raster-conversion

I'm using TINinterpolation in QGIS/pyQGIS to interpolate rasters from point-based model results.

Subsequent post-processing to produce a series of rasters containing index values at the same resolution and spatial extent in R produces result rasters that are much smaller (with individual files taking up 10-50% of the disk space). All of the rasters are stored on disk as GeoTIFF files.

Importing and exporting the input rasters in R using `raster()` then `writeRaster()` shrinks the filesize of the input rasters without noticeably changing the values.  The re-processed rasters appear to be the same, and a couple of quick benchmark tests didn't show significant performance differences when reading them in to R using `raster()`

Are there settings within QGIS/pyQGIS to produce smaller rasters and avoid the extra step?

Is there a reason I should avoid re-processing and use the original larger files?  I don't specify a compression, and do not think it defaults to a lossy compression.

The pyQGIS code I use to produce the rasters is:

```py
layers = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layers()
feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback() 
for layer in layers:
    layerType = layer.type()
    ext = layer.extent()
    xMin = ext.xMinimum()
    xMax = ext.xMaximum()
    yMin = ext.yMinimum()
    yMax = ext.yMaximum()
    nCols = (xMax-xMin)/3.2808
    nRows = (yMax-yMin)/3.2808
    coords = "%f,%f,%f,%f [EPSG:2285]" %(xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax)
    if layerType == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
        for i in range(0,len(use_cols)):
            col = use_cols[i]
            output_file_name = layer.name()+"_"+col_names[i]
            export_file_name = interim_path + output_file_name+".tif"
            vlayer = source_geopackage+"|layername="+layer.name()+"::~::0::~::"+str(col)+"::~::0"
            processing.run("qgis:tininterpolation", {
            'INTERPOLATION_DATA':vlayer,
            'METHOD':0,'COLUMNS':nCols,'ROWS':nRows,
            'EXTENT':coords,
            'OUTPUT': export_file_name},
            feedback = feedback)
```

Resulting rasters are 2.95 to 30.5 MB on disk

Using an example file that is 3.34MB on disk
Properties from QGIS:

Original
bb60_2_291_Depth
Name
bb60_2_291_Depth
Source
D:/GIS/BarkleyBear/Model Results/bb60_2_20180806 - 1/bb60_2_rasters/bb60_2_291_Depth.tif
Provider
gdal
CRS
USER:100001 - * Generated CRS (+proj=lcc +lat_1=47.5 +lat_2=48.73333333333333 +lat_0=47 +lon_0=-120.8333333333333 +x_0=500000.0000000001 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs) - Projected
Extent
1801231.2298138733021915,525557.9680938507663086 : 1805139.4590218793600798,534789.2082456786883995
Unit
feet
Width
1302
Height
3077
Data type
Float64 - Sixty four bit floating point 
GDAL Driver Description
GTiff
GDAL Driver Metadata
GeoTIFF
Dataset Description
D:/GIS/BarkleyBear/Model Results/bb60_2_20180806 - 1/bb60_2_rasters/bb60_2_291_Depth.tif
Compression
LZW
Band 1
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=15.99194996506
STATISTICS_MEAN=1.6378313050893
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=2.3352375055995e-006
STATISTICS_STDDEV=1.4764189154989
More information
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Dimensions
X: 1302 Y: 3077 Bands: 1
Origin
1.80123e+6,534789
Pixel Size
3.00171,-3.00008

In R reading this output raster in resaving it:

```
y <- raster(files_list[1])
writeRaster(y,paste0(output_folder,x)
```

and properties from QGIS for the resulting 1.63MB file:

Original
bb60_2_291_Depth
Name
bb60_2_291_Depth
Source
D:/GIS/BarkleyBear/Model Results/bb60_2_20180806 - 1/bb60_2_rasters/reprocessed/bb60_2_291_Depth.tif
Provider
gdal
CRS
USER:100001 - * Generated CRS (+proj=lcc +lat_1=47.5 +lat_2=48.73333333333333 +lat_0=47 +lon_0=-120.8333333333333 +x_0=500000.0000000001 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs) - Projected
Extent
1801231.2298138730693609,525557.9680938509991392 : 1805139.4590218788944185,534789.2082456790376455
Unit
feet
Width
1302
Height
3077
Data type
Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point 
GDAL Driver Description
GTiff
GDAL Driver Metadata
GeoTIFF
Dataset Description
D:/GIS/BarkleyBear/Model Results/bb60_2_20180806 - 1/bb60_2_rasters/reprocessed/bb60_2_291_Depth.tif
Compression
LZW
Band 1
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=15.99194996506
STATISTICS_MEAN=nan
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=2.3352375055995e-006
STATISTICS_STDDEV=nan
More information
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Dimensions
X: 1302 Y: 3077 Bands: 1
Origin
1.80123e+6,534789
Pixel Size
3.00171,-3.00008

The entire list, in this case ranges from 1.26 to 4.37 MB on disk, with a small list of rasters going from 93.8 MB to 23.4 MB.

Comment: Can you show the output of `gdalinfo` on large and small rasters? That will tell us if the resolution or bit depth has been changed and any compression algorithm used. `gdalinfo` is a command line utility but is also available in R from the `gdalUtils` package and is essentially what QGIS shows as the properties of a raster - you could cut and paste info from that instead.

Comment: @Spacedman I updated with the properties from QGIS, and it does look like the bit depth changes from 64 bit floating point to 32 bit floating point.